# Servlet shows blank page when using println in method other than doGet or doPost

Tags: servlets

My dynamic web app is showing a blank page when using println in a method other than doGet or doPost. The default page loads fine. On it is a form that has an input that's passed to the startup servlet's doPost, and then it's request, response gets passed to a second servlet's doPost. Then the same request, response gets passed to an output method than uses println to display the output. But I'm getting a blank page instead of the output. I know that the output method gets called because I was getting an error with it when I initially tried using a BufferedWriter to write to an output file, but that wasn't working. This is my first attempt at a Java EE dynamic web app and using println, although I have intermediate experience with PHP, ASP.Net and several languages in desktop apps.

The second servlet's doPost method calls the methods of readnums, sort, and outputSort. The readnums method reads a text file for the program to use. I'm having problems with relative paths (that's why I couldn't get the BufferedWriter to work in outputSort, I suppose). The path I'm using for the input text file is "/WebContent/WEB-INFO/myfile.txt". Will I have a problem with this once the web app is deployed with a hosting site? At the risk of asking 2 questions in one, how do you correctly specify relative paths to the app? I've Googled and Googled but can't seem to find a working solution. When I try to use getServletContext().getRealPath() I get an error in the outputSort method at that line. I didn't try to use it in the readnums method yet. I've got a website that I can hotlink to for the input files if that is a viable alternative. How would you do that?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Initial servlet called from the default jsp:

```
package com.LAEWeb;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public  class Startup extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        req.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/Startup.jsp").forward(req,resp);

    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {


        String sorts = req.getParameter("sorts");

        String action = req.getParameter("action");


        if ("Powerball".equals(action)) {

            Powerball p = new Powerball();

            p.sortInputText = sorts;

            p.doPost (req, resp);
        }

         else if ("Mega Millions".equals(action)) {

            // Invoke SecondServlet's job here.
        }

    }
}
```

The second servlet's methods (I didn't list readnums and sort for brevity):

```
  @Override
  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req,
            HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {


        if (PB_operation == "sorts") {

            readnums();

            if (!errorMessage.isEmpty())  {

                resp.setContentType("text/html");
                PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

                try  {

                  out.println("<html>");
                  out.println("<body>");
                  out.println("<h2>Input file not found</h2>");
                  out.println("</body>");
                  out.println("</html>");

                 } finally {

                  out.close();
                 }

                return;


            }

            else {

                sort();

                outputSort(req, resp);


            }

        }

  }


void outputSort (HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException  {

    String  Temp;
    int i;

    resp.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();

    try  {

    out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");

    out.println("<html>");

    out.println("<head>");

    out.println ("<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>");

    out.println("<title>LAEWeb</title>");

    out.println("</head>");

    out.println("<body>");

    out.println("<a href=\"/Startup.jsp\">Return to previous page </a>");

    out.println("<h2>The Powerball sorted totals for the range selected</h2>");

    out.println("<pre>");

    out.println("Rank     Numbers     Totals        Power ball     Totals");
    out.println ("");
    out.println ("");

    for (i = 1; i <= NUMLIMIT; i++)  {

        Temp = "<p>" +  Integer.toString(i) + "   ";

        if (i < 10)

            Temp += " ";

        Temp +=  Integer.toString(sortnums[i][1]) + "     ";
        Temp +=  Integer.toString(sortnums[i][2]) + "     ";

        if (i <= XLIMIT) {

            Temp +=  Integer.toString(sortxball[i][1]) + "     ";
            Temp +=  Integer.toString(sortxball[i][2]) + "     ";

        }

        out.println (Temp);

    }

    out.println("</pre>");

    out.println("</body>");

    out.println("</html>");

    } finally  {

    out.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: You'll need to use `getRealPath()`. Personally I'd keep the file on the classpath, though. In any case, the root of web content from the *app's* point of view is `/`, e.g., `WEB-INF/blah.txt`.

Comment: @Dave Newton Thanks. I appreciate it. What's the correct way to use getRealPath()?

Comment: The first part of your second servlet works right? Right-click on your web page and select "View Page Source" to see which part of your page is printed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used getServletContext().getRealPath() in the first servlet and passed the path to the second servlet through a class variable in the second servlet. That worked. Thanks for your help Ali for pointing me in the right direction. I guess since the second servlet is not actually initializing normally (I'm just calling it's doPost from the first servlet) the context for it is null. Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get real path of a relative path you can use `getRealPath()` method, for example:

```
String realPath = getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INFO/myfile.txt");
```

If you're using this code in `init()` method of your servlet, use:

```
config.getServletContext().getRealPath("/WEB-INFO/myfile.txt");
```

To answer first part of your question, I need more information about it. I'll edit this answer after getting information.

Comment: I tried what you suggested. I get a 'NullPointerException" on that line.

Comment: No. I used it in another method of the servlet.

Comment: @te7: Or another method that you've called from doGet or doPost method. right?

Comment: Yes. Another method that I called from doPost. My starting servlet's doPost processes input from the starting jsp, then calls doPost in my second servlet, which calls another method which tries to use the line.

Comment: Maybe I'm getting a 'NullPointerException' because the second servet's context is NULL. Should I use the line in the first servlet and pass the path?

Comment: @te7: You can check it, but in your doPost method it shouldn't be null.

Comment: @te7: Did you try `req.getServletContext().getRealPath()`?